# SQL Server timestamp correct -> javascript Date wrong

Tags: javascript, sql-server, timestamp, ssms, timestamp-with-timezone

We live in the US Central Timezone, so 6 hours behind UTC time.  We are storing a timestamp in a SQL Server DB for each comment inserted using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  When I view the database in SQL Server Management Studio, it shows the correct current CST time.  So if I entered a comment right now and my computer time says it is 9:31, the DB would show 9:31 for the comment entered.  I'm not sure if that is correct or if it is supposed to be showing the UTC time which according to https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc is 15:31 right now.

So I am grabbing out the comment and data from the DB with Node and passing them into our React app.  Once in React, I run this code to convert the timestamp to a js Date object: `const commentDate = new Date(comment.date);`.  Now when I console that out is is showing 6 hours behind the current time.  So currently I am manually adding 6 hours after converting to a Data object to get the correct time.  Obviously this is less than ideal.  I imagine after the DST switch, this will no longer be correct.

So where is my issue?  Is it the way I am storing it in the DB?  Should it actually say 15:31 when I view the DB?  Or is it the way I am parsing/converting it when I get it into my javascript?

Comment: This doesn't fix the underlying issue, but perhaps you might be better off with a UTC time from SQL Server? `GETUTCDATE()` or `SYSUTCDATETIME()`.

Comment: A little hard to understand what you're saying here.  The actual data that's stored in your database should be UTC time.  But, both the server-side "viewer" that you're using and the Javascript-side code will probably each be displaying it to you in "their" time-zone.  Check the database carefully what time-zone is being used in the actual data that's in those tables.  Be sure that what comes across in your queries ... made by JavaScript or otherwise ... are also UTC values.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Let me know what I need to clear up in my text.  I didn't think about the SQL client changing the time as well.  I will look into that.  So if it is coming across to my Javascript as UTC values, how do I convert properly to CST?

Comment: From all the documentation I have read so far, SQL Server Management Studio does not automatically convert the time to the local time for display.

Comment: Gosh I have a similar problem ! And is totally clear to me what you are asking. Were you able to fix that? If so, please share how

Comment: @JorgeLopez I don't think I ever got to the root of the issue.  I simply put a bandaid on it but manually changing the time by 5 or 6 hours when I display it in the app.

Comment: sorry, I actually did managed to fix it. When you read UTC date from SQL server add this method to your date: [yourDateFromSQL].toISOString().substring(0, 10)